# C++11: (recursive) pointer arithmetic in templates (TMP)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, metaprogramming

Don't ask me why, but I was trying to initialize an array of pointers at compile-time (the pointers point to elements of another static array). This involves TMP and therefore template-recursion while building a variadic list. I've narrowed the problem down to the following:

```
template <int const * const P>
struct Foo
{
    constexpr static int const * const bar = P;
};

constexpr int const array[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; // global, so has linkage

int main()
{
    /* 1 */ cout << *Foo<array>::bar << '\n';
    /* 2 */ cout << *Foo<array + 1>::bar << '\n';
    /* 3 */ cout << *Foo<&array[1]>::bar << '\n';
}
```

Case 1 works fine, and prints '0'.

Case 2 does not compile, and GCC (4.9.1) complains:

```
error: ‘(((const int*)(& array)) + 4u)’ is not a valid template argument for ‘const int*’ because it is not the address of a variable
 cout << *Foo<array + 1>::bar << '\n';
                       ^
```

Case 3 does not compile, and GCC complains:

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
 cout << *Foo<&array[1]>::bar << '\n';
```

I'm mainly concerned about Case 2. Why is it not possible to do constant pointer-arithmetic and pass the result to a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that it's not possible to do any pointer arithmetics when specifying non-type template arguments of pointer type. The standard says so explicitly, C++11 14.3.2/1:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type, non-template *template-parameter* shall be one of:
>
> - ...
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and
>     external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates
>     and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, **expressed (ignoring parentheses) as
>     `&` *id-expression*,** except that the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall
>     be omitted if the corresponding *template-parameter* is a reference; or
> - ...

(Emphasis mine, omitted other bullet points which don't apply here).

For completeness, *id-expression* is defined in 5.1.1 as either a qualified or unqualified identifier, operator name, destructor name or template identifier. `[]` is not allowed there.

Comment: Wow thanks, that was fast. Well, if the standard says so... But do you have any idea why? I mean... what kinds of horrible things could happen if the standard would allow for simple pointer-arithmetic?

Comment: @JorenHeit Sorry, I haven't tried thinking about it. Such counterexamples are usually quite devilish, so even if I can't think of a consequence, it wouldn't surprise me a bit to learn of one or three.